# Expected '}' but eof found

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play framework 2.5.10
Compilation Error is `}' expected but eof found.`.
I failed to match some miss code. Where to debug?

Here is my Book.java in models

```
package models;

public class Book{

    public Integer id;
    public String title;
    public Integer price;
    public String author;

    public Book(Integer id, String title, Integer price, String author){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.author = author;
    }

    private static Set<Book> books;

    static {
        books = new HashSet<>();
        books.add(new Book(id: 1, title: "C++", price : 10, author: "ABC");
        books.add(new Book(id: 2, title: "Java", price : 20, author: "DEF");
    }

    public static Set<Book> allBooks(){
        return books;
    }

    public static Book findById(Integer id) {
        for (Book book : books) {
            if (id.equals(book.id)) {
                return book;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void add (Book book){
        books.add(book);
    }

    public static boolean remove(Book book){
        return books.remove(book);
    }
}
```

And this is compilation error

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 3 Java sources to /Users/Play/PROJ_NAME/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /Users/Play/PROJ_NAME/app/models/Book.java:46: `}' expected but eof found.
[error] }
[error]  ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 3 Java sources to /Users/Play/PROJ_NAME/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /Users/Play/PROJ_NAME/app/models/Book.java:46: `}' expected but eof found.
[error] }
[error]  ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application - 

! @7a6fl9c3b - Internal server error, for (GET) [/books] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[`}' expected but eof found.]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: First of all, fix your indentation. Then check it thoroughly and properly using IDE or code editors

Comment: In future, you can paste the code, highlight it and press ctrl-k to have StackOverflow add the required initial spaces.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to destroy the formatting. Also, don't keep adding "Thank you" to your questions. I understand omitting it is considered rude in some parts of the world, but here it serves no purpose.

Comment: I'll just be careful from now. Thank you for your nice advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `static` block is off, and you're missing any `import`(s). Java doesn't have a named dictionary parameter syntax, it should look something like

```
private static Set<Book> books; // do not use raw-types

static {
    books = new HashSet<>(); // diamond operator
    books.add(new Book(1, "C++", 10, "ABC")); // need to close the .add() call
    books.add(new Book(2, "Java", 20, "DEF"));
}

public static Set<Book> allBooks() {
    return books;
}
```

And make sure you

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
```